# How can I store the results of python program so I don't have to re-run all the code next time?

Tags: python, text, storing-data

I am working on a big project and only part of it is done. The part which is done requires some time to execute and I'd like to store the output of my program on my computer so I don't have to re-run what's been written so far. The data I need to save is a list of long strings which contain text from pdf's that I'm extracting data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Python Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). This will allow you to save python objects to a file and load them at a later date while still being fully functional. A lot of people use Pickle to save their trained neural networks.

If you are just trying to save a list of strings you can easily just:

```
with open("save.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(my_list_here)

with open("save.txt", "r") as f:
    my_list = f.readlines()
```

Please let me know if this helps or if you have any further questions.

Comment: Using `with` is recommended with file handles as it will ensure it is closed, added edit.

Comment: Also maybe since these are long strings, we would want to read them line by line instead of slurping all lines with `readlines()`

Comment: @RazzleShazl Never had any issues with using close instead of with but either way accepted the edit. Also as long as he uses writelines() the file will have \n delimiters so there should be no issue then using readlines will break each list item by the \n delimiter.

Comment: Using close is perfectly fine, except you must wrap the contents in a `try` to ensure it does indeed close when an exception is raised, thats all.  Using `with` means we can skip this boilerplate.

Comment: Consider using `readline()` instead of `readlines()` if you are worried about loading too much data at once.  The former returns a line at a time, the latter an array containing the entire file.

Comment: docs for how to read and write to files: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Also I forgot to add `:` on both open lines, and this edit dialogue wants me to edit 6 character.